# Got PayloadTooLargeError when try to upload file to firebase storage using node js and busboy

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, body-parser

I'm trying to upload video file (14 MB) to google firebase storage using firebase cloud functions, Busboy and node js. But I got following error during file upload. This function works with small files without any issue.

> PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
>     at readStream (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
>     at getRawBody (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
>     at read (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:77:3)
>     at rawParser (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\raw.js:81:5)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>     at trim_prefix (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>     at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>     at Function.process_params (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>     at next (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>     at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:100:7)

These are my code files

index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require('express');
const FBAuth = require('./util/fbAuth');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { db } = require("./util/admin");
app.use(express.json({limit: 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 200}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 200}));
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 200}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 200 , extended: true }));

const {
  uploadItem
} = require('./handlers/uploads');

app.post('/upload', FBAuth, uploadItem );

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

upload.js

```
const { db, bucket } = require('../util/admin');
const BusBoy = require('busboy');
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require("../util/config");

exports.uploadItem = (req, res) => {
  console.log('file upload started')
  console.log('data : ' + req.body.name);
  const busboy = BusBoy({headers: req.headers});
  let dataFileName;
  let fileTobeUploaded = {};
  let formData = {};
  busboy.on(
    "field",
    (fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) => {
      formData = { ...formData, [fieldname]: val };
    },
  );
  busboy.on('file',(name, file, info) => {
    const { filename, encoding, mimeType } = info;
      //my.image.png
      const fileExtension = filename.split('.')[filename.split('.').length - 1];
      //12345678900.png
      dataFileName = `${Math.round(Math.random()*100000000000)}.${fileExtension}`;
      const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), dataFileName);
      fileTobeUploaded = {filepath, mimeType};
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath)); 
  })
  busboy.on('finish', () => {
    req.body = formData;
      bucket.upload(fileTobeUploaded.filepath, {
          resumable: true,
          metadata:{
              metadata:{
                  contentType:fileTobeUploaded.mimeType
              }
          }
      })
      .then( () => {
        const fileUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o/${dataFileName}?alt=media`
        const newUpload = {
          uploadItemUrl: fileUrl,
          userHandle: req.user.handle,
          userImage: req.user.imageUrl,
          createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
          likeCount: 0,
          commentCount: 0
        };
          
        db.collection('uploads').add(newUpload)
      })
      .then( () => {
       
          return res.json({message: "File Uploaded Successfully"});
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
          return res.status(400).json({ error : err.code});
      })
  });
  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
}
```

Please help me to resolve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Prasad, could you try to increase the limit of your `body-parser` to like 50mb. 
`app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));` and see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB Thanks for your comment. but I still get  the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Resource Limit](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits) Documentation, the maximum data limit can be sent in HTTP Function is 10 mb only for Cloud Function 1st Gen. There is no way to get this limit increased. You could use Cloud Function (2nd gen) to get  a 32mb limit instead. You may check the Cloud Function (2nd gen) [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/2nd-gen/2nd-gen-differences).

However, You can still let the client upload directly to storage. Authenticated onto his own user folder and security rules limiting the file size to whatever size you wish into a temp folder. You can use either [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#prereq-code-samples) or [Upload files with Cloud Storage on Web](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#prereq-code-samples).

Comment: Thank you. I implement direct upload from web.